# Issue on creating simple jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to work out why I am not able to set color of each `div` based on its own attribute on `data-color`.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.helloplugin = function() {
    let color = this.data('color');
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).html('<h2>Hello jQuery</h2>').css('color', color);
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.helloplugin').helloplugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="helloplugin" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="blue"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="green"></div>
```

Comment: I think it's the logic of your `.each()` statement. `color` is set to `red` and then applied to each element.

Comment: That's right but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript: **[HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)**:

**`this.dataset.color`**

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.helloplugin = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).html('<h2>Hello jQuery</h2>').css('color', this.dataset.color);
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.helloplugin').helloplugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="helloplugin" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="blue"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="green"></div>
```

You can use **[Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)**: Full browser support:

**`this.getAttribute('data-color')`**

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.helloplugin = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).html('<h2>Hello jQuery</h2>').css('color', this.getAttribute('data-color'));
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.helloplugin').helloplugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="helloplugin" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="blue"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="green"></div>
```

**Full jQuery version:**

**`$(this).data('color')`**

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.helloplugin = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).html('<h2>Hello jQuery</h2>').css('color', $(this).data('color'));
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.helloplugin').helloplugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="helloplugin" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="blue"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="green"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Danny but what is `dataset` how it is holing the color?

Comment: The dataset property on the HTMLElement interface provides read/write access to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element. By using `this.dataset.color` you are getting directly the data-color of your HTML element.

Comment: is this supported in all browsers?

Comment: It is supported by most browsers. IE 11.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can replace `this.dataset.color` by `$(this).data('color')`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.helloplugin = function() {
    var that = this;
    that.each(function() {
      $(this).html('<h2>Hello jQuery</h2>').css('color', $(this).data("color"));
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.helloplugin').helloplugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="helloplugin" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="blue"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="green"></div>
```

You must loop over all the elements, collect the color inside the loop and then apply it to that element. Your example was collecting the color first, then looping over the elements.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Twisty but I am not getting the `var that = this` can you please let me know what is this doing?

Comment: @Beheini this just helps create an alternate reference to ensure that `this` does not get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following code.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.helloplugin = function() {
    this.each(function(e) {
      let color = $(this).data('color');
      $(this).html('<h2>Hello jQuery</h2>').css('color', color);
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.helloplugin').helloplugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="helloplugin" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="blue"></div>
<div class="helloplugin" data-color="green"></div>
```